# Generic types java : Type Safety warning

Tags: java, class, generics, nested, generic-type-argument

I'm getting a type safety warning when I want to use the class of a generic class in a generic class, the code bellow will better explain :

```
class A<U, V> {

    private class B<W, X> {
        X x;
        W w;
    }

    public A() {
        B<U, V> c = C.someMethod(B.class); // warning here
    }

    static class C {
        public static <T> T someMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea to solve this ?

Please note that B class is private.

Comment: you can probably declare the function as `public static <T, X, Y> T<X, Y> someMethod` and then type inference will do the job, but that's just moving the problem of how are you going to build an instance of `B<U, V>` from `B.class`. That will require a cast to `T<X, Y>`, which will have the same type safety warning.

Comment: There's nothing you can do except suppress the warning.  Class literals will have raw types.

Answer (score 0):

Your work is not correct when set a type that is not important for compiler in this line:

```
B<U, V> c = C.someMethod(B.class);
```

To compiler, just B is a sign of panic.
so you should write.

```
B<?, ?> c = C.someMethod(B.class);
```

Comment: c needs to be of type B<U, V>